# Count the occurrences of how many events user hasn't responded

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, left-join

Taking into account the tables provided below, I want to be able to count the occurrences of how many `Events` a `User` still hasn't provided `availability` yet.

Table `users`

```
|    name | id |
|---------|----|
|    John |  1 |
| Francis |  2 |
|   Peter |  3 |
|    Mike |  4 |
```

Table `events`

```
| id |    name |
|----|---------|
|  1 | Event 1 |
|  2 | Event 2 |
```

Table `availability`

```
| answer | event_id | user_id |
|--------|----------|---------|
|    yes |        1 |       1 |
|    yes |        2 |       1 |
|     no |        1 |       2 |
|  maybe |        2 |       4 |
```

The expected answer would then be:

Expected answer:

```
| user_id | count |
|---------|-------|
| 1       | 0     |
| 2       | 1     |
| 3       | 2     |
| 4       | 1     |
```

I have been able to do a query for how many events each member has responded, but looking for how many *hasn't* responded.

DBFiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mwv4F1wYZ9UxB56L9mMjFQ/1

SQL:

```sql
create table events (
    id   int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(100) null
);

create table users (
    name varchar(100) null,
    id   int auto_increment primary key
);

create table availability (
    answer  text null,
    event_id int  null,
    user_id int  not null,
    constraint availability_events_id_fk
        foreign key (event_id) references events (id),
    constraint availability_users_id_fk
        foreign key (user_id) references users (id)
);

INSERT INTO events (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Event 1');
INSERT INTO events (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Event 2');

INSERT INTO users (name, id) VALUES ('John', 1);
INSERT INTO users (name, id) VALUES ('Francis', 2);
INSERT INTO users (name, id) VALUES ('Peter', 3);
INSERT INTO users (name, id) VALUES ('Mike', 4);

INSERT INTO availability (answer, event_id, user_id) VALUES ('yes', 1, 1);
INSERT INTO availability (answer, event_id, user_id) VALUES ('yes', 2, 1);
INSERT INTO availability (answer, event_id, user_id) VALUES ('no', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO availability (answer, event_id, user_id) VALUES ('maybe', 2, 4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `cross join` tables `users` and `events` to generate all possible combinations, and then `left join` table `availability`. Then, aggregation and a conditional `sum()` give you the expected result.

```
select
    u.id user_id,
    sum(case when a.event_id is null then 1 else 0 end) cnt
from users u
cross join events e
left join availability a 
    on a.event_id = e.id and a.user_id = u.id
group by u.id
order by u.id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cbc7718f7c79f2bc2d635fea19dda3fa)**:

```
user_id | cnt
------: | --:
      1 |   0
      2 |   1
      3 |   2
      4 |   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this by pre-aggregating the availability table:

```
select u.user_id, (e.num_events - a.cnt)
from users u left join
     (select a.user_id, count(*) as cnt
      from availability a
      group by a.user_id
     ) a 
     on u.user_id = a.user_id cross join
     (select count(*) as num_events from events) e;
```